# MessageBox Function Prepending String to Return Value

Tags: .net, powershell, messagebox

I have the following function, which retrieves the current user's SID, displays it in a `MessageBox` and then returns the SID value:

```
function Get-UserSid {
    $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)
    $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    MsgBox $strSID.Value

    $strSID.Value
}
```

[image]

This appears to work fine at first, but if I call this function from elsewhere, e.g.:

```
function SecondFunction {
    $usersid = Get-UserSid
    MsgBox $usersid
}
```

The SID suddenly has "OK" prepended to it:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? I assume it has something to do with the "OK" button in the `MessageBox` being copied to the return value - but why would it do this?

**MsgBox Function:**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

function MsgBox {
    param (
        [string]$message
    )

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message)
}
```

Comment: `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message)` -> `$null = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MsgBox function is placing the results of the `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message)` command on the pipeline.

You can either assign it to a variable and ignore it

```
function Get-UserSid {
    $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)
    $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    #Ignore this...
    $ignore = MsgBox $strSID.Value 

    #return the SID
    $strSID.Value
}
```

or pipe it to `Out-Null`

```
function Get-UserSid {
    $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)
    $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

    #Ignore this...
    MsgBox $strSID.Value | Out-Null

    #return the SID
    $strSID.Value
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks Christopher. Just been having a look at the documentation and found that `MessageBox` returns a `DialogResult` value, which I am assuming is the "OK" in my example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or assign it directly to `$null`: `$null = MsgBox $strSID.Value`